# AWS Quicksight for real-time dashboards

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

Is AWS Quicksight a good option for real-time dashboards that continuously show live data coming from IoT devices?

I have a Kinesis data firehose that updates an S3 bucket every 5 minutes or less and I am seeing that at best I can schedule quicksight datasets to auto-load data from the S3 data source every hour and not earlier. This works, but it is really not real-time.

Is there anything that can make Qucksight dashboards update itself real time? If not, what would be the other options within the AWS ecosystem? Grafana?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I ended up using AWS Grafana with AWS Timestream for this. That seemed to be a better choice for real-time graphics.